# Get List of users in Agora.io voice discussion room who do not publish stream

Tags: javascript, agora.io

It is possible to get list of streamID by

```
client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode, codec});
client.on('stream-subscribed'
```

But it is available only when the user publish stream

```
client.publish(localStream
```

[[[ Question ]]]

I want to see list of users who do not publish the stream but join in the room by

```
client.join(null, 'room-name', 'user-id');
```

As the user can hear the stream when that user joined the room without publishing own localStream.
Therefore I want to show all the audiences even if they do not publish the stream.

For the purpose to save bandwidth, 
it is better not to publish  localStream, and just subscribe voice.
Therefore I want to recognize all users even if they do not publish stream

Comment: You can use signaling and send a signal from a user when joins the room

Answer (score 0):

Add a signaling System to the existing code so that a signal is sent to all user when a user joins the system. If it needs to be more perfectly implemented u can track user streams and do the listing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `peer-online` event (*Occurs when a remote user or host joins the channel.*)

```
client.on('peer-online', function(evt) {
  console.log('peer-online', evt.uid);
});
```

See full list of `on` events within Agora.io's Docs: 
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.client.html#on

### Update

per the comments below, this method only works in `communication` mode where all users have the broadcast role. In `live` mode there isn't a way to get the users using the Agora RTC SDK, but you can use the [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/product_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms) to count the users in a channel.

The Agora RTM SDK allows you to create a data channel that each user joins along with the Live Video Broadcast. Agora RTM allows you to [check the number of users in an RTM Channel before joining](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/classes/rtmclient.html#getchannelmembercount) or after joining the RTM channel, you can use the `MemberJoined` and `MemberLeft` [Channel Events](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/interfaces/rtmevents.rtmchannelevents.html) to listen for new users.

Comment: "peer-online" can know peers who has joined later
but how user can know existing peers?

Comment: All client.on event listeners should be assigned before you call the method join the channel. once the client joins the channel, the events will trigger all users in the channel

Comment: 'peer-online' for Audience works only with "rtc" mode and it does not work with "live" mode.

Is it a correct behavior?

I am thinking using "live" mode and wanted to know the audience, but is it not possible?

Comment: "'peer-online'" is triggered with less than 17 people. is it a limitation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but will try to answer, the 17 broadcasters is a "soft" limit. if you wish to have more than 17 broadcasters you will have to selectively subscribe to streams. Having 17 a/v streams is very bandwidth and CPU intensive operation so the device will lag on the decoding of the streams.  Zoom and other software that "supports" more than 17 host, is doing this selection under the hood.

Comment: I am not talking about "host" but I am talking about "audience". By using 'peer-online'  I want to know list of all audience in the room. However, I can get only 17 audiences, even if there are more people in the room

Comment: Only the number of host users had the soft limit. Audience doesn’t have a limit. As mentioned above, peer online only works for hosts so you will need to use Agora RTM to know audience users

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification, getMembers of AgoraRTM does not mean members of AudioBroadcasting, but it is a member of the messaging, and AudioBroadcasting audiences should join messaging. is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

Pinging all the available streams periodically might help in understanding when someone has entered the room but not streaming.

Comment: what is the specific problem that is facing you? edit your question to ask about the specific problem you are facing and try to provide a code example so others can help, thanks.

Comment: this won't work because there is no way to "ping" all channels from the SDK.